# java: when a new object is allocated in heap, what is created in heap?

Tags: java

when a new object is allocated in heap, what is created in heap?
for example: `Info info = new Info();`

a referrence is created in stack and a new Info object is created in the heap, but what is
created in the heap, and the data created in heap have any differents to the type data of Info class in the method area.

Comment: You answered it yourself, the actual object is created in the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Storage space for the non-static instance variables (also for super-classes) and some bookkeeping information (for example the class of the object) will be allocated in the heap.

The methods (code) are provided in the .class file, they are not represented in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following url :

Here it is clearly and simply explained about the memory management in java.

http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-jvm-memory-types/